# Is it advisable to split a large Dictionary into multiple parts?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dictionary

I'm using a Dictionary to hold a rather large number (> 10^7) of items. Could it improve lookup and/or insertion performance if it gets split into multiple individual dictionaries, each holding a fraction/partition of the data?

For the sake of an example, imagine we have a `Dictionary<int,int>`. We could replace it with:

```
var ds = new Dictionary<int,int> [256];
// ...
void Add (int key, int value) {
    // We can assume key is an evenly distributed hash
    ds[key & 0xFF].Add (key, value);
}
// Lookup similar
```

Of course this is something that needs to be benchmarked, but I'm also interested in general advice for this situation. Surprisingly, I could not find a really similar question here.

I'm aware that there is a limit to the number of items that a single Dictionary can hold. This question assumes this limit is not an issue - else, there would be only one solution anyway.

Comment: It shouldn't matter - a .NET Dictionary is already implemented as a hashed container, so your splitting up is just doing a second hash to subdivide into other hashed containers.  Unless you got really lucky with your distribution of data with your first hash function, I'd guess (at first glance) your proposed solution would be no better than just using the Dictionary.

Comment: The only way to tell if having multiple dictionaries is better is, as you suggest, to benchmark it yourself. We don't have any idea how you are keying your dictionary right now, so there's not a lot we can do to help. If you have a way to subdivide your data, it might help. With that many items though, I might suggest a third party service like Elasticsearch for example.

Comment: According to mi tests, it crashed on memory on 48*10^6 items for 32bit and 96*10^6 items for 64bit. So this is a strictly theoretical question. I think the the opportunity to improve is on higher level - what do you need this for?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Good catch, the typo was off by one order of magnitude. -- I need a cheap in-memory KVS for batch processing in some rather large statistics calculation thing I'm working on. But the question is really meant to be more broad.

Answer (score 1):

I've thought about this some more. While many data structures exhibit logarithmic cost for insertion or lookup operations, in Dictionaries these are (amortized) assumed to be O(1).

In the former case, splitting off a fraction of the work by indexing manually (an O(1) operation) could reduce the remaining work by reducing the logarithmic parameter. Effectively, we would be implementing a dictionary on top of another structure.

Of course, this also means that this should not have any significant effect when the base structure itself is already a dictionary. There are many ways to implement these, but as far as I am aware none could benefit asymptotically by reducing their size: Their average case behavior (i.e. handling of duplicates) is constant in time and does not grow.

On the other hand, manual work introduces overhead. So we would expect such a sliced dictionary to perform worse.

To sanity-check this, I wrote up a small test.

```
Console.WriteLine ("Times in seconds per 10m merged/sliced operations");
foreach (var init in new[] { "empty", "size", "spare" }) {
    for (int n = 10 * 1000 * 1000; n <= 40 * 1000 * 1000; n += 10 * 1000 * 1000) {
        for (int repeat = 0; repeat < 3; repeat++) {
            Stopwatch wmi, wml, wsi, wsl;

            {
                GC.Collect ();
                var r = new Random (0);
                Dictionary<int, object> d;

                if (init == "empty") {
                    d = new Dictionary<int, object> ();
                }
                else if (init == "size") {
                    d = new Dictionary<int, object> (n);
                }
                else {
                    d = new Dictionary<int, object> (2 * n);
                }

                wmi = Stopwatch.StartNew ();
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    var key = r.Next ();
                    d[key] = null;
                }
                wmi.Stop ();

                wml = Stopwatch.StartNew ();
                var dummy = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    dummy ^= d.ContainsKey (i);
                }
                wml.Stop ();
            }

            {
                GC.Collect ();
                var r = new Random (0);
                var ds = new Dictionary<int, object>[256];

                for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                    if (init == "empty") {
                        ds[i] = new Dictionary<int, object> ();
                    }
                    else if (init == "size") {
                        ds[i] = new Dictionary<int, object> (n / 256);
                    }
                    else {
                        ds[i] = new Dictionary<int, object> (2 * n / 256);
                    }
                }

                wsi = Stopwatch.StartNew ();
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    var key = r.Next ();
                    var d = unchecked(ds[key & 0xFF]);
                    d[key] = null;
                }
                wsi.Stop ();

                wsl = Stopwatch.StartNew ();
                var dummy = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    var d = unchecked(ds[i & 0xFF]);
                    dummy ^= d.ContainsKey (i);
                }
                wsl.Stop ();
            }

            string perM (Stopwatch w) => $"{w.Elapsed.TotalSeconds / n * 10 * 1000 * 1000,5:0.00}";
            Console.WriteLine ($"init = {init,-5}, n = {n,8};"
                + $" insert = {perM (wmi)}/{perM (wsi)},"
                + $" lookup = {perM (wml)}/{perM (wsl)}");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine ();
}
```

Each test is repeated three times. The initialization strategy for the dictionary is one of:
a) empty (let it handle growth itself)
b) init to size (capacity equals number of items)
c) init to twice size

Note that the sliced dictionaries may experience some uneven distribution.

Output (small numbers are better):

```
init = empty, n = 10000000; insert =  1.17/ 1.22, lookup =  0.42/ 0.53
init = empty, n = 10000000; insert =  1.13/ 1.24, lookup =  0.41/ 0.53
init = empty, n = 10000000; insert =  1.10/ 1.21, lookup =  0.41/ 0.53
init = empty, n = 20000000; insert =  1.19/ 1.29, lookup =  0.42/ 0.53
init = empty, n = 20000000; insert =  1.18/ 1.28, lookup =  0.42/ 0.54
init = empty, n = 20000000; insert =  1.18/ 1.28, lookup =  0.42/ 0.53
init = empty, n = 30000000; insert =  1.31/ 1.22, lookup =  0.34/ 0.66
init = empty, n = 30000000; insert =  1.35/ 1.23, lookup =  0.35/ 0.66
init = empty, n = 30000000; insert =  1.34/ 1.21, lookup =  0.35/ 0.66
init = empty, n = 40000000; insert =  1.26/ 1.20, lookup =  0.43/ 0.76
init = empty, n = 40000000; insert =  1.26/ 1.19, lookup =  0.43/ 0.76
init = empty, n = 40000000; insert =  1.25/ 1.21, lookup =  0.43/ 0.76

init = size , n = 10000000; insert =  0.82/ 0.89, lookup =  0.48/ 0.79
init = size , n = 10000000; insert =  0.80/ 0.90, lookup =  0.48/ 0.70
init = size , n = 10000000; insert =  0.80/ 0.88, lookup =  0.47/ 0.69
init = size , n = 20000000; insert =  0.84/ 0.91, lookup =  0.48/ 0.69
init = size , n = 20000000; insert =  0.84/ 0.88, lookup =  0.48/ 0.69
init = size , n = 20000000; insert =  0.84/ 0.85, lookup =  0.48/ 0.69
init = size , n = 30000000; insert =  0.88/ 0.90, lookup =  0.49/ 0.75
init = size , n = 30000000; insert =  0.93/ 0.96, lookup =  0.50/ 0.72
init = size , n = 30000000; insert =  0.88/ 0.90, lookup =  0.49/ 0.73
init = size , n = 40000000; insert =  0.85/ 0.90, lookup =  0.48/ 0.76
init = size , n = 40000000; insert =  0.86/ 0.98, lookup =  0.49/ 0.76
init = size , n = 40000000; insert =  0.86/ 0.94, lookup =  0.49/ 0.76

init = spare, n = 10000000; insert =  0.69/ 0.73, lookup =  0.29/ 0.49
init = spare, n = 10000000; insert =  0.70/ 0.71, lookup =  0.29/ 0.49
init = spare, n = 10000000; insert =  0.68/ 0.76, lookup =  0.28/ 0.49
init = spare, n = 20000000; insert =  0.70/ 0.78, lookup =  0.29/ 0.54
init = spare, n = 20000000; insert =  0.70/ 0.78, lookup =  0.29/ 0.53
init = spare, n = 20000000; insert =  0.70/ 0.76, lookup =  0.29/ 0.53
init = spare, n = 30000000; insert =  0.71/ 0.77, lookup =  0.29/ 0.50
init = spare, n = 30000000; insert =  0.73/ 0.78, lookup =  0.30/ 0.51
init = spare, n = 30000000; insert =  0.71/ 0.77, lookup =  0.29/ 0.51
init = spare, n = 40000000; insert =  0.72/ 0.80, lookup =  0.29/ 0.53
init = spare, n = 40000000; insert =  0.72/ 0.81, lookup =  0.29/ 0.53
init = spare, n = 40000000; insert =  0.72/ 0.81, lookup =  0.29/ 0.53
```

Consistently, neither insertion not lookup are faster in sliced dictionaries. I believe this will be the case in most circumstances.

However, there is still a possible use case for such a sliced dictionary in parallel operation. Different parts of the dictionary can work on insertion, lookup, etc of a batch operation's data in parallel.

This is true regardless if the dictionary as a whole is used concurrently. However, if it is, then the slicing would allow locking only required parts instead of everything (in a naive implementation). Other dictionaries designed for concurrent operation from ground up (e.g. .NET's `ConcurrentDictionary`) are exempt from this disadvantage, however.

Comment: There is a measurable difference if you change the primary hash funtion to `ds[(uint)i>>24]`. It is probably because it improves memory locality in *this test*. The question is, how much is the test representative for the real case.

Comment: Good point and I missed talking about that at all. To explain your idea: In the answer I silently used almost the worst case of memory locality for the lookup: Almost every item refers to a different of the sub-dictionaries due to the `index & 0xFF`. Chaning it to `index >> 24`, on the other hand, is the best case, because subsequent indexes refer to the same slice. Obviously, the latter case has a lot of potential to be faster. Measuring this, my results agree with yours: It becomes significantly faster (factor 1.5 to 2.5 on my box). So if memory locality can be assumed, slicing may be useful

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the dictionary in one piece will give you the best average performance, but you'll get big hits every time it needs to [`Resize`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs.html#bba8e22685381014) its internal array.

```
// Create the dictionary
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>(19998337); // 90 msec

// Populate the dictionary
for (int i = 0; i < 19998337; i++) dict.Add(i, i); // 850 msec

// Add one more entry that requires resize
dict.Add(-1, -1); // 850 msec
```

This will happen only few times, and you can probably avoid it by allocating space aggressively at the creation of the dictionary. Splitting the huge dictionary to multiple smallish dictionaries is certainly another way to amortize this cost.

---

**Update:** I had the concern that calling `GetHashCode` twice per method, one for selecting the correct sub-dictionary and another one internally by the selected sub-dictionary, could affect performance. Some implementations of `GetHashCode` are a bit expensive, like the one for case-insensitive strings ([`StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.currentcultureignorecase)). I thought that I had found a clever solution by implementing a special `EqualityComparer` that caches the result of the last `GetHashCode` invocation, but actually the performance gains are minimal. My benchmarks showed no tangible improvement for simple key-types like `int`, and less than 10% speedup overall for the aforementioned case-insensitive strings. At the same time this optimization has the drawback that read operations are mutating the internal state, so a [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim) cannot be used for thread synchronization.

In any case, here is my implementation of this idea:

```
public class SegmentedDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private class CachedComparer : IEqualityComparer<TKey>
    {
        private readonly IEqualityComparer<TKey> _source;
        private int? _cachedHashCode;

        public CachedComparer(IEqualityComparer<TKey> source)
        {
            _source = source ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
        }

        public bool Equals(TKey x, TKey y) => _source.Equals(x, y);

        public int GetHashCodeAndCache(TKey key)
        {
            int hashCode = _source.GetHashCode(key);
            _cachedHashCode = hashCode;
            return hashCode;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(TKey key)
        {
            if (_cachedHashCode.HasValue)
            {
                int hashCode = _cachedHashCode.Value;
                _cachedHashCode = null; // Use the cache only once
                return hashCode;
            }
            return _source.GetHashCode(key);
        }
    }

    private readonly CachedComparer _comparer;
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue>[] _segments;

    public SegmentedDictionary(int segmentsCount, int capacityPerSegment,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        _comparer = new CachedComparer(comparer);
        _segments = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>[segmentsCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < segmentsCount; i++)
        {
            _segments[i] = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(
                capacityPerSegment, _comparer);
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> GetSegment(TKey key)
    {
        var hashCode = _comparer.GetHashCodeAndCache(key);
        var index = Math.Abs(hashCode) % _segments.Length;
        return _segments[index];
    }

    public int Count => _segments.Sum(d => d.Count);

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get => GetSegment(key)[key];
        set => GetSegment(key)[key] = value;
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) => GetSegment(key).Add(key, value);

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) => GetSegment(key).ContainsKey(key);

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
        => GetSegment(key).TryGetValue(key, out value);

    public bool Remove(TKey key) => GetSegment(key).Remove(key);

    public void Clear() => Array.ForEach(_segments, d => d.Clear());

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
        => _segments.SelectMany(d => d).GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    ICollection<TKey> IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Keys
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    ICollection<TValue> IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(
        KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Contains(
        KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.CopyTo(
        KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(
        KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.IsReadOnly
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Every resize roughly doubles the size. It means, number of items copied on resize is roughly equal to actual capacity of dictionary. Total resize overhead for one big dictionary and more smaller dictionaries would be about the same.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek true. But if you are doing something real-time, like streaming the frames of a video, you may want to avoid these infrequent large hiccups.